# Subsite with different template, and content

Tags: multisite

I have a Wordpress blog hosted on a shared web server: http://martinnormark.com

I would like to add a whole new "area" to this site, called Consulting. When navigating to http://martinnormark.com/consulting - another template with different navigation should be used, and the frontpage should be blog posts for that specific area.

This also means, that the blog posts I write for the Consulting area should not be displayed on the front page of the root domain.

I use the Genesis framework, but I think that might be my problem. It doesn't seem to support this setup.

Any suggestions for frameworks, themes, or plugins?

**Code**

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( !$query->is_category('hardware')) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Comment: So the "hardware" cat has an id of 1? It looks like "Uncategorized" is id 1 (http://martinnormark.com/?cat=1) looks like hardware has an id of 30 (http://martinnormark.com/?cat=30) so the code should be `$query->set( 'cat', '-30' );`

Comment: Boooom! It works, it's just me that didn't fully understand the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework is not the problem. You just need to exclude your Consulting category from the loop each time you have it. Then use a custom template for the marketing page. Another option would be to set up a multi-site install and then use Consulting as its own blog.

**EDIT:**

To exclude the category try adding this to your themes function.php

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( !$query->is_category('consulting')) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Edit 2: fixing the problem chip mentioned below.

Comment: Excluding the posts from the consulting category doesn't seem to work. I add its ID to the exclusion list in Genesis settings, but it doesn't exclude the posts... Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure how Genisis does it but see edit.

Comment: Don't you want to use `is_category( 'consulting' )` instead of `is_page( 'consulting' )`, so that the conditional is testing for the *consulting **category archive** page*, rather than for a *static page* named "Consulting"?

Comment: @ChipBennett You're right my bad.

Comment: I can't get that working. Right now there's one post in the Hardware category on my blog: http://martinnormark.com and I have added your (updated) code to the bottom of the functions.php and chenged 'consulting' to 'hardware' - but the Hardware post is still present on the front page. Any idea? The post on the front page is "The (almost) Ultimate Developer PC 2.0", a little below the middle of the page.

Comment: did you set the `-1` to your 'hardware' cat id?

Comment: Yes, the code from the bottom of my functions.php is now posted to my question.